# MVC3 pass the parameter to others in same controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to pass the parameter, which is 'priceValue'. How can I pass this value through using RedirectToAction? or do you have any idea for that?
I am trying to make shopping cart now. 'priceValue' is radioButton value. Could you give me some help? After passing the priceValue, and I want to use if statement what I have written in AddToCart. Is it possible to use it?
Please help me..
Thanks.

```
public class ShoppingCartController : Controller
{
rentalDB db = new rentalDB();
    //
    // GET: /ShoppingCart/
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var cart = ShoppingCart.GetCart(this.HttpContext);

        // Set up our ViewModel

        var viewModel = new ShoppingCartViewModel
        {
            CartItems = cart.GetCartItems(),
            CartTotal = cart.GetTotal()
        };

        // Return the view
        return View(viewModel);
    }


    // GET: /Store/AddToCart/5
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddToCart(int id, FormCollection col)
    {
        var addedProduct = db.Product
            .Single(product => product.productId == id);
        decimal priceValue = Convert.ToDecimal(col["price"]);
        //how to pass priceValue to index
        if (Convert.ToDecimal(col["price"]) == addedProduct.threeDayPrice)
        {
            ViewBag.price = new SelectList(db.Product, "productId", "threeDayPrice");
            //How to put this value into cart.AddtoCart(addedProduct) with date and price
        }
        else if (Convert.ToDecimal(col["price"]) == addedProduct.aWeekPrice)
        {
            ViewBag.price = new SelectList(db.Product, "productId", "aWeekPrice");
            //How to put this value into cart.AddtoCart(addedProduct) with date and price
        }

        // Retrieve the product from the database
        // Add it to the shopping cart
        var cart = ShoppingCart.GetCart(this.HttpContext);

        cart.AddToCart(addedProduct);

        // Go back to the main store page for more shopping
        //I don't know how to pass the 'priceValue' by using RedirectToAction.
        return RedirectToAction("Index", new {id = priceValue});
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add a parameter to your Index method in order to be able to get the value passed in to the Index method:

```
public ActionResult Index(int priceValue = 0).
```

Instead of 0, you can then use whatever default value you wish.  Then calling

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", new {@priceValue = priceValue});
```

will allow you to get the value inside the method.

Comment: Thank you for responding! I have got it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", new {@id = priceValue.toString()});
```

will redirect it to an Action method called Index with a id parameter